# tableView header does not update data Swift

Tags: swift, uitableview

I have set up a tableView in a ViewController. This table view has 1 section, 2 prototype cells: one is used to return the number of rows in section, the other one is used to display a custom header. 
The data I want to load in the labels in the header is generated every time a row is selected. The problem is that when the ViewController is first loaded and every time a row is selected, the data is not updated in the labels in header.
If I press the back button and return to the ViewController which holds the header, the data will be updated in the labels attached on the header. 
What am I doing wrong?

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return frequency.count
}

func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let  headerCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("customheader") as! CustomHeader

    headerCell.dateHeaderlabel.text = StructS.headerDate
     headerCell.hourHeaderlabel.text = StructS.headerHours + "-"
      headerCell.totalHoursHeaderlabel.text = String(StructS.numberHours)
       headerCell.priceHeaderlabel.text = String(StructS.price)
        headerCell.backgroundColor =  UIColor(red:72/255,green:141/255,blue:200/255,alpha:0.9)
    tableView.reloadSections(NSIndexSet(index: 0), withRowAnimation: .None)
       return headerCell
}


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 70.0
}
```

[image: Before]   [image: After]

Comment: you need to reload your tableview after updatting the data.

Comment: @UmairAfzal If I do  `self.tableView.reloadSections(NSIndexSet(index: 0), withRowAnimation: .None)` I get another error: `Expected declaration.` Can you tell me where should I place the code?

Comment: @bogdanbarbulescu show the code were you load the data

Comment: you should use this code "self.tableview.reloadData()"   and use this code where you are updating data.(putting new values to table view)

Comment: @UmairAfzal    Here is a [LINK](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5e9d61e3ca0985f27eec7337bea2fd39) to my code.

Comment: put "self.tableview.reloadData()" at the end of your didSelectRowAtIndexPath method

Comment: @UmairAfzal     I did it and it works. Every time I selected a row, the header is updated. Another issue. When the ViewController is first loaded, the header is not updated, so I need to update the data in the header with the info generated according to the row that was previously selected (saved in NSUserDefaults). How would I go about calling this method `func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) ` in ViewDidLoad?

Comment: I have explained it in answer please accept the answer if it helps you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever user tap on a cell didSelectRowAtIndexPath method is called. So what you can do is save the selected value in NSUserDefaults and then poulate your section header by getting that value from user defaults. In this way when you will come back to the tableview you will see last selected row's data in your section header.

Comment: If I use NSUserDefaults, I will have to write a lot of code as I will have many more labels in the section header. I was wondering if there is a more elegant way to update my data in ViewDidLoad, using a function, or ...

Comment: yes there are elegant ways, I told you NSUserDefaults because you was already using it.

Comment: I have accepted your answer. If you have the time, please update your answer with that elegant way on how to load the data in the header section in ViewDidLoad. Hope others will find the second solution useful too. Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you have a UITableView object in a UIViewController.
Set the UIViewController in Main.storyboard as  dataSource and delegate. Next in your subclass of UIViewController, set self as the delegate and datasource for the table view.
       override func viewDidLoad() {
        self.tableView.delegate = self
        self.tableView.dataSource = self
 }

When the ViewController is first loaded, the header labels are not updated, so you need to update the data in the header with the info generated according to the row that was previously selected (saved in NSUserDefaults).

```
 override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    // retrieve indexPathForCellSelected from NSUserDefaults
  if let retrievedIndexPath = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().dataForKey(indexKey) {
if let data1 = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(retrievedIndexPath) as? NSIndexPath {
    indexPathForCellSelected = data1

    // inform the delegate that the row has already been selected
           self.tableView(self.tableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath: indexPathForCellSelected!)

} 
     // handle the selection of the row so as to update the values of labels in section header
     if indexPathForCellSelected == nil {
        // construct an indexPath for the row we want to select when no previous row was selected ( not already saved in NSUserDefaults)
            let rowToSelect:NSIndexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: 1, inSection: 0)

      /* select the row at `rowToSelect` indexPath. This will just register the selectd row, However,the code that you have in tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath: is not yet executed because the delegate for the tablewView object in the ViewController has not been called yet. */

         self.tableView.selectRowAtIndexPath(rowToSelect, animated: true, scrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition.None)

        // inform the delegate that the row was selected
        // stackoverflow.com/questions/24787098/programmatically-emulate-the-selection-in-uitableviewcontroller-in-swift
             self.tableView(self.tableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath: rowToSelect)
    }

}
```

Comment: @Umair Afzal     I have added an answer to my previously mentioned issue. If you have any thoughts on this, please share them.